# Batch rename script to rename/replace square brackets

Tags: script, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks, batch-rename

I am currently using Windows Server 2003 and would like to create a schedule task or command to run which would batch rename and replace all square brackets '[]' from file names and replace them with parentheses '()'

for example if I have a file called:

```
Information1-102-5022.34[0001].doc
```

I would like it to rename to:

```
Information1-102-5022.34(0001).doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new .bat:

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Original=["
Set "Replaced=("

For %%a in (*.doc) Do (
Set "File=%%a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Original%=%Replaced%!"
)
```

Copy-paste and adapt for "]" to ")".