# batch script to replace square brackets, across a whole drive?

Tags: rename, batch-rename

I found a fabulous script to help with a recent virus attack, which replaces the square brackets in a filename. However, the virus managed to hit a large number of different filepaths before it was stopped.  Could this script

[Batch rename script to rename/replace square brackets](https://superuser.com/questions/890918/batch-rename-script-to-rename-replace-square-brackets)

be amended to run across a whole file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) to loop through files and
recurse on subfolders.

Untested modification of the `.bat` file from your link:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Original=["
Set "Replaced=("

For /R C:\ %%a in (*.doc) Do (
Set filename=%%~na%%~xa
call set newname=!filename:%Original%=%Replaced%!
Ren "%%a" "!newname!"
)
```

Comment: on testing this new batch it gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect." errors.  Is the C:\ a requirement for the /R suffix?

Comment: My part of the /R was correct. It was the script in your link that was sh*t. Corrected.